# Incrementing the value of a variable by one

Tags: vba, excel

Incrementing the value of a variable by one is often achieved in other basic dialects in ways like

```
myreallylongandawkwardvariable ++
```

or

```
inc(myreallylongandawkwardvariable)
```

Is the only way to achieve this in VBA to code like this?

```
myreallylongandawkwardvariable = myreallylongandawkwardvariable +1
```

Comment: Yes, that is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the only standard way to increment a variable with VBA.

If you really want to, you can create a custom procedure:

```
Sub Increment(ByRef var, Optional amount = 1)
    var = var + amount
End Sub
```

Then you can do the following:

```
Increment myreallylongandawkwardvariable      'Increment by 1
Increment myreallylongandawkwardvariable, 5   'Increment by 5
```

Comment: What happens if the optional amount isn't parsed?

Comment: It has a default value of 1 if it isn't passed as an argument.

Comment: Thank you. There are so many ways VBA could be improved but I guess one has to be grateful that it is around at all. As a Mac user, I've been out in the wilderness for a couple of years before VBA was reintroduced in Office 2011.

Comment: One thing is mysterious to me about the syntax though. In the declaration of the procedure "Increment", the parameters are enclosed by parentheses. When I type "Increment" to call the procedure, the little yellow help text box showing the expected syntax also has the parameters inside parentheses. But if I do write the parameters that way, the operation is not carried out. Instead, I have to provide the parameters without parentheses like in Phylogenesis' example. It seems illogical – but – as long as it works one way or the other...

Comment: @DanBaeckström This is one of those silly "features" of VB/VBA. Surrounding the parameters with parentheses says you're calling a function (a procedure that returns a value) and you're not allowed to ignore its return value. If you're calling a procedure that doesn't return anything (or you want to ignore its return value) you do not use them.

Answer (score 0):

@DanBaeckström, that is Not strictly correct.
If you call a procedure simply by its name, as in:
Increment myreallylongandawkwardvariable
you don't use parentheses.
But, if you precede this procedure call with the keyword "Call", as in:
Call Increment(myreallylongandawkwardvariable)
you MUST use parentheses.

Comment: This should be a comment under the original answer, if not they can't get alerts to your mentions